# Only accept numeric characters in batch file input

Tags: batch-file, cmd, character

I am making a game from a batch file and one of the inputs can accept any character (~!@#$%^&*()`) and any other. Is there any way to look for any character other than numbers and use the GOTO command? This is my script so far:

```
set /p guess=
echo "%guess%"|findstr /L "[a-z][A-Z]~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+\^|^^;:"',<.>/?*"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto Invalid_Number
if %guess% == %number% goto Correct
... everything else here ...

:Invalid_Number
echo Invalid Number. Input must be a number
pause
```

Is there any way to make this work, all it says is Access Denied, I am testing this on a school computer though, it might not work.

Answer (score 4):

```dos
:ask    
    set /p "guess=?" || goto :ask

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("!guess!") do set "guess="
    endlocal & set "guess=%guess%"

    if not defined guess (
        echo invalid input
        goto ask
    )

    echo valid input
```

The basic idea behind the test is to use the numbers as delimiters in a `for /f` command, so they are removed from the input. If anything remains it is not a number and the code in the `do` clause is executed.

The `delayedexpansion` is enabled/disabled to handle problematic characters (specially double quotes) that could be typed in the input field.

Comment: Thank you so much, there is a problem, If the guess var includes & it says & was unexpted, can you help?

Comment: @JacobRocks12,  i can not reproduce the indicated behaviour. For me, the posted code works with all input, including `&`.

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the bottom of your script:

```
:isInt <str>
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%1") do exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

Then to invoke it, do

```
call :isInt %guess% && success || fail
```

Here's a more complete example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /a rand = %RANDOM% %% 10 + 1

:begin
set /P "guess=Guess a number between 1 and 10: "

call :isInt %guess% || goto invalid

if %guess% gtr 0 if %guess% lss 11 (
    if %guess% equ %rand% (
        echo Lucky guess!
        exit /b
    ) else (
        echo Oooh, so close.  Try again.
        goto begin
    )
)

:invalid
echo Please enter a valid integer between 1 and 10.
goto begin

:isInt <str>
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%1") do exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

This is the same basic idea as MC ND's solution, but instead of using the `for` statement to unset `%guess%`, it sets `%errorlevel%` and stops looping at the first non-numeric character.  This makes it infinitesimally more efficient.  :)

And with either success or fail, I like to use [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) (the `&&` and `||` stuff).

Comment: Nice, but : 1) While the `call` makes the code more organized (and yes, i usually code that way) the `call` command is SLOW and makes the full process less efficient. 2) Have you tried to input a single `"`? The delayed expansion used in the `in` clause was included to avoid this kind of problems on input validation.

Comment: Good points :)  Is `call` really slower than `goto`?  I suppose it makes sense, since `call` invokes a child runtime.  Still faster than `findstr` or similar, though.

Comment: `call` makes aditional tests not present in `goto` , but obviously it is faster not to `call` nor `goto` to do the test.  But `call` does not execute a child runtime. The batch file is executed inside a *"batch context"* in memory. The `call` command creates a new *"batch context structure"* in memory (independtly of calling another batch or calling a label in current batch),  and is executed inside the same running cmd instance after swapping pointers to the new *"context"*. On end of called code, its *"context"* is discarded and the caller *"context"* regains control

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest you a different, better approach? Instead of read any line and then check if it contains a number, your program may directly read a number, so the checking is not necessary. The way to do that is *emulating* `SET /P` command via a subroutine. This way, you may add additional constraints to the input, like read a maximum number of digits, for example.

```
@echo off

rem Read a number emulating SET /P command
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

setlocal
rem Define the following variable before call InputNumber subroutine
set "thisFile=%~F0"

call :InputNumber number="Enter a number of up to 5 digits: " 5
echo Number read: %number%
goto :EOF


:InputNumber var="prompt" [digits]

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize variables
if "%~3" equ "" (set numDigits=9) else set "numDigits=%3"
set "digits=0123456789"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%thisFile%" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"

rem Show the prompt and start reading
set /P "=%~2" < NUL
set "input="
set i=0

:nextKey
   set "key="
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /W "%thisFile%" "%thisFile%" 2^>NUL') do if not defined key set "key=%%a"

   rem If key is CR: terminate input
   if "!key:~-1!" equ "!CR!" goto endRead

   rem If key is BS: delete last char, if any
   set "key=!key:~-1!"
   if "!key!" equ "!BS!" (
      if %i% gtr 0 (
         set /P "=!BS! !BS!" < NUL
         set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
         set /A i-=1
      )
      goto nextKey
   )

   rem If key is not a digit: ignore it
   if "!digits:%key%=!" equ "%digits%" goto nextKey

   rem If can not accept more digits: ignore it
   if %i% equ %numDigits% goto nextKey

   rem Else: show and accept the digit
   set /P "=%key%" < NUL
   set "input=%input%%key%"
   set /A i+=1

goto nextKey

:endRead
echo/
endlocal & set "%~1=%input%"
exit /B
```

You may also add any other processing to the input line, like show asterisks instead of digits, etc. For a large example on this topic, see [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5775)